# How to read local csv file as ndarray using Rust

Tags: csv, rust, rust-ndarray

I recently went through Rust documentation and found that you can directly read `CSV` as `ndarray`. The only thing that makes me concerned, looks like you need to know the shape of the file you read in advance.

Here's the code from the Rust docs:

```rust
extern crate csv;
extern crate ndarray;
extern crate ndarray_csv;

use csv::{ReaderBuilder, WriterBuilder};
use ndarray::{Array, Array2};
use ndarray_csv::{Array2Reader, Array2Writer};
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // Our 2x3 test array
    let array = Array::from(vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).into_shape((2, 3)).unwrap();

    // Write the array into the file.
    {
        let file = File::create("test.csv")?;
        let mut writer = WriterBuilder::new().has_headers(false).from_writer(file);
        writer.serialize_array2(&array)?;
    }

    // Read an array back from the file
    let file = File::open("test.csv")?;
    let mut reader = ReaderBuilder::new().has_headers(false).from_reader(file);
    let array_read: Array2<u64> = reader.deserialize_array2((2, 3))?;

    // Ensure that we got the original array back
    assert_eq!(array_read, array);
    Ok(())
}
```

It was taken from [here](https://docs.rs/ndarray-csv/latest/ndarray_csv/).

I tried this:

```rust
fn read_csv(path_to_file: &str) -> Result<Array2<u64>, Box<dyn Error> > {
    let file = File::open(path_to_file);
    let mut reader = ReaderBuilder::new().has_headers(true).from_reader(file);
    Ok(reader.deserialize_array2((210, 2)))
    }

 let array = read_csv("data/train_data_5exp.csv")?;
 println!("{:?}", array);
```

For some reason, this function doesn't read even with the provided shape of the file.

The document example is not quite working for me since I want to read `CSV` with an unknown shape. How can I make a function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the csv file / data?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to replace this

```
let array_read: Array2<u64> = reader.deserialize_array2((2, 3))?;
```

with this

```
let array_read: Array2<u64> = reader.deserialize_array2_dynamic()?;
```